# Data entered alters string length

Tags: javascript, string, function, alter

I am new to JavaScript and I have been doing some work creating a form in HTML and JavaScript. In this work I have been trying to limit the string of a field depending on the text entered into a previous field.

What i have been trying is if the country 'Australia' is entered into the 'Country' text box than the 'Postcode' text box is limited to only 4 numbers (the Australian postcode standard)

i have done this much of a function so far:

```
document.getElementById('txtcountry').onblur = function postcode()
{
var country = document.getElementById('txtcountry').value;
if (country == "Australia" || category == "australia")
{
    document.getElementById('txtpostcode').maxLength = 4;
    }
    else
{
    document.getElementById('txtpostcode').maxLength = 9;
}
}
```

Here is the segment of the initial HTML that i have to use the function with:

```
<b>Postcode:</b> <input type="text" id="txtpostcode" name="postcode">
<br>
<b>Country:</b> <input type="text" id="txtcountry" name="country">
```

I am calling the function using :

```
<form name="rego" action="submit.htm" onsubmit="return !!(validateText() & validateCheckBoxes(this) & validateRadioButton() & validateEmail() & populateInstitution() & postcode());" method="POST">
```

Any help would really be appreciated!

UPDATE: i have updated my function to the finished function after some help as it doesn't seem to work and i need some further help with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to set the `maxLength` property:

```
var pc = document.getElementById('txtpostcode');
pc.maxLength = 4;
pc.value = pc.value.substr(0,4); // remove any extra characters already entered
```

...and then add an `else` condition to set the `maxLength` to whatever your default is for other countries.

You would then call your `postcode()` function from the `blur` event of your `txtcountry` field.

EDIT: Note that the function you've shown has an undefined variable `category` in the second part of the `if` test - should be `country`. And as I mentioned already you do need to call the function from somewhere.

Comment: maxLength was exactly what i was looking for except for some reason after i finished the function it didn't seem to work

Comment: See my edit. And of course you do need to actually _call_ the function. Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/nnnnnn/hk6bE/

Comment: <form name="rego" action="submit.htm" onsubmit="return !!(validateText() & validateCheckBoxes(this) & validateRadioButton() & validateEmail() & populateInstitution() & postcode());" method="POST">

Comment: Oh my fault, i have figured out my error, thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I would use the

```
var country = document.getElementById('txtcountry');
if (country.value == "Australia" || category == "australia")
{
  country.setAttribute("maxlength","4");
  country.value = country.value.substr(0,4);
}
```